# How to make sure color is overwritten on hover?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, css-specificity

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hovertest" style="background-color: #fff">
    Test 1
</div>
<div class="hovertest" style="background-color: #eee">
    Test 2
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hovertest:hover {
     background-color: #000;
}
```

The hover color does not get applied due to the higher specificity of the inline color style. Same problem if I give an ID to the divs and apply their individual color in the ID styling. I want to share the hover color definition across both divs (or more), while displaying their unique color on non-hover. Is this possible without a lot of redundant css?

Comment: Use `!important` in **CSS** code. `background-color:#000 !important;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can outweigh any specificity of other declarations in CSS by setting `!important` after the value. Overriding this is only possible with another declaration with `!important`.

```
.hovertest:hover {
    background-color: black !important;
}

#hovertest:hover {
    background-color: red; /* Even using an ID won't override `!important` */
}
```

**But be careful!** Using `!important` in your CSS can result in some really tricky issues. It's often more useful to write your CSS in a way where you avoid using it as much as possible.

**Don't use `!important` *reactive*, use it *preventive*.**

Comment: Excellent! Yeah, I wanted to avoid any custom code to remove the background color (as I would have to add it back when the mouse no longer hovers). I've never found an actual use for !important that made sense, so thanks for the example. I will remember that rule.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to write more code instead of using `!important` to just kinda "sneak" around the issue. Most times I've tried to use important styles in the past resulted in more problems. Just keep this in mind, when you encounter new issues. ;)